# Not all %include in a SAS program are executed and I don't get any error message

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I want to schedule a project monthly, but my SAS server is installed on Linux, so I thought of creating a program as a master, which would execute each of these programs using the %include function.

This idea works, at least executing some statements. The problem is that when it goes to run program number 08, the rest of the %include statements are not run. It treat them like comments. It doesn't return any type of error in the log and I don't know the possible reason of this.

If it helps, the first 7 programs take approximately 1h 30min, and generate 90 data sets in the WORK library.

**Master.sas**

```
%include "/sas/data/my_program_01.sas";
%include "/sas/data/my_program_01.sas";
...
%include "/sas/data/my_program_27.sas";
```

The only thing I can think of would be to split the master into multiple master programs, just to reduce the number of %include per program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard to say as long as we don't know what the content of your programs is (especially program_07 and program_08), and how the log exactly looks like. A reasonable explanation would be that your program_07 has some sort of error or typo in the end, for example a single ".
Then all the rest of your programs would be treated as comments.

Comment: Thank you gregor!! that was the problem, some programs had comments at the end and they were not well closed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set OPTIONS SOURCE2; so you can see what is being generated. Guess is that you have an unbalanced quotation mark and it is commenting out code. Bring it into EG and look for it, especially in 07

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other comments here, try to comment out your program_07 and program_08, to see if there is an issue with your syntax, or you have a more interesting problem.

Also, check the log. With all the options enabled, to get as detailed log as possible. It is quite likely you will find the issue that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of %INCing the programs I would use SYSTASK to run the programs.  You would get a SAS log and listing for each program.  Errors in one program would cause others to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I you want to run your script in batch, you shouldn't use the work library to store you data.
If there is any error in one of the sub program, you have to relaunch every steps.

The best solution would be to create a bash script that launch each programs and to run it with crontab (if you have not access to a better scheduler).

https://blogs.sas.com/content/sgf/2017/12/19/running-sas-programs-in-batch-under-unix-linux/